# You (root) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration centOS

Tags: linux, bash, cron, centos7

I am getting this error when I do.

```
crontab -e
You (root) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.
```

I commented everything under

```
cat /etc/pam.d/crond
#
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon
#
#
# No PAM authentication called, auth modules not needed
#account    required   pam_access.so
#account    include    password-auth
#session    required   pam_loginuid.so
#session    include    password-auth
#auth       include    password-auth
```

I added below in `/etc/security/access.conf`

```
#+ : ALL : ALL
#+ : root : cron
```

Here is cron log

```
Sep 19 21:01:01 localhost crond[65409]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:01:01 localhost crond[65409]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:02:01 localhost crond[65541]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:02:01 localhost crond[65541]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:03:01 localhost crond[65677]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:03:01 localhost crond[65677]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:04:01 localhost crond[65785]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:04:01 localhost crond[65785]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:05:01 localhost crond[65892]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication failure)
Sep 19 21:05:01 localhost crond[65892]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication failure)
```

root password was set never to expire

```
chage -l root
Last password change                    : never
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 90
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

I restarted crond several times nothing helped.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) OR http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer https://serverfault.com/questions/620157/how-to-fix-a-crontab-access-issue-with-a-pam-configuration-error-message for solution.

it seems you should not comment the root in the access.conf.
There are other solutions in the same link as well

Hope it solves your issue.